# How to connect to the Internet using a dial-up modem on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, ppp

I got a dial-up ISP connection as my backup ISP.
I have a Digisol modem which has a single RJ45 port which I have connected through a switch to a Ubuntu desktop. The ISP gave me a username and password for the modem to be used.
It appears that I need to use gnome-ppp to access it and set the username and password. I do not like Network Manager on Ubuntu so I usually purge it as the first step after Ubuntu installation.

My first problem is that I am unable to install gnome-ppp on Ubuntu 22.04. I tried "sudo apt-get install gnome-ppp" and it ends up complaining "Unable to open package gnome-ppp"  Interestingly, I am able to install it on Ubuntu 18.04.  How do I get around this?

Also, is there any other alternative to gnome-ppp?

Comment: Just use a browser to access the router and set it that way. Some years back but that it how I managed ppp setup.

Comment: @John Thanks a lot.  I was surprised that the ISP wants me to buy a separate router from them. Huawei EG8141A5. The Digisol model I have is DG GR6010 which I think does not require a separate router. It  has one RJ45 Gigabit LAN port and one PON port for the incoming fiber. The Digisol manual is available at https://www.digisol.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DG-GR6010-QIG-Made-In-India.pdf.  I do not think I need a separate router. If you have time, please take a quick look at the manual and let me know if I would need an additional router.

Comment: The manual  page  7 says manage your existing router at 192.168.1.1 . User is Admin  and Password is stdONU101  .  That should work with what you have.

Comment: @John Thanks a lot. I was able to log in earlier too. Its just that there are a bit too many options that I will need to figure out. I will give it a try.

Comment: I did this a while back.  Look for connections:   Cable, DSL, PPP and so on. Should be easy to locate.